# I am trying to lookup if a record already exist in a table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to see if a record already exist for a patient's permanent address. I tried the folowing code but it's giving me error as Data type mismatch in criteria expression matched . The AddressType is a textbox and ClientCategory is a Number. I have put the code onload event of the mainform:

```
If Not IsNull(DLookup("ID", "TableAddresses", "ID = '" & Me.PatientID & "' And AddressType = '" & "Permanent" & "' And ClientCategory = '" & Me.ClientCategory & "'")) Then
    Me!FrmClienPatientAddressViewsubform.Form!SameAsLocal.Value = True
Else                 
    Me!FrmClienPatientAddressViewsubform.Form!SameAsLocal.Value = False
End If
```

Comment: Is PatientID text or a number type?  If number try `"ID = " & Me.PatientID & " And `

Answer (score 0):

Something seems wrong here.

`ID` normally is a unique key, thus this should be the only value needed to look up the record:

```
If Not IsNull(DLookup("ID", "TableAddresses", "ID = " & Me.PatientID & "")) Then
    Me!FrmClienPatientAddressViewsubform.Form!SameAsLocal.Value = True
Else                 
    Me!FrmClienPatientAddressViewsubform.Form!SameAsLocal.Value = False
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the rule is: Strings within apostrophes, Integers without apostrophes.

If Gustavs solution isn't the right one and you need the other parameters, the solution could be:

```
Me!FrmClienPatientAddressViewsubform.Form!SameAsLocal.Value = _
    Not IsNull(DLookup("ID", "TableAddresses", "ID = " & Me.PatientID & _
    " And AddressType = 'Permanent' And ClientCategory = " & Me.ClientCategory))
```